# Transform panel displays "No Shape Properties" in illustrator cc 2014

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator CC - 2014.  When I create a rectangle after selecting "Rectangle Tool (A)" from left side tool bar, rectangle is created and the transform panel displays "Rectangle Properties" as under;
[image]

However, when I create any other shape whether, triangle, polygon or circle in the same way, the transform panel displays "No Shape Properties" as under:
[image]

Is it a version problem?  Or am I missing something to work.  Please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to this question can be easily found in the software's help files or online manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stars are not Live Shapes - and so have "no shape properties" in the Transform panel.

However if you update to CC 2018, polygons and ellipses do have shape properties. I think this feature was first introduced in CC 2015.

Since you have an Adobe CC cloud subscription, updating is free.

Comment: Yeah its so useful to have live properties for a ractangle. I mean ist not like changing a rectangle, even a rounded one couldn't be done without these, while a star clearly needs no such thing, for one modifying it is more annoying and god forbid you wanted more star arms. Anyway the way adobe does this is totally idiotic, it should work more like how blender or maya works allowing me to define the properties.

Comment: @joojaa Inkscape has live star shapes with round corners, and inner and outer radius controls.  It can actually be quite useful for all sorts of things, from cog wheel shapes, and more freaky shapes. [see examples here](https://imgur.com/a/myLauyu).

Comment: Yes but thats not terribly useful (cogwheels aren't stars btw! as a cogwheel requires either a involute or cycloid shapes. Im a Mech Eng after all), it would be more useful if you could define your own rules (well i can but thats a different thing most of you can not), just like you can in maya and blender. See can you do spirals, involutes, arrowheaded thin pie graphs, lego pieces with varying lengths. Both maya and Blender can do this and allow you to change the values without the software devs ever needing to know how to do these. You can right there in the GUI without a single line of code

Comment: @joojaa - I'm not talking about designing for real mathematically correct cogwheels, I mean it's useful for stylised graphics.  There is actually a cogwheel extension in Inkscape too.

Comment: Yes and im not ataking about inventing things with stuff others give you but things that are actually useful to you day to day that you decide what they are.

Comment: You are right, Illustrator CC 2014 does not support these properties, but I tried it on Illustrator CC 2018 which support these.  Here, I wish to clarify as to  why I was interested in these properties is that the new version supports increasing / decreasing polygon corners even after they are created.